# Residually nilpotent vs residually p

Tags: gr.group-theory

A well-known theorem of Gruenberg implies that a finitely generated residually torsion-free nilpotent group is residually $p$-finite for all primes $p$. What about the converse?

**Question:**
Are there any examples of a finitely generated group $G$ with the properties that $G$ is residually $p$-finite for all primes $p$, but $G$ is not residually torsion-free nilpotent?

Comment: Right now I can't even find an example residually-$p$ for infinitely many $p$ and not RTFN. 

Comment: @Yves: Neither can I. For any finite collection of primes $\Pi$, ${\rm SL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ has a finite index subgroup $K$ which is residually-$p$ for each $p \in\Pi$. But of course $K$ is not RTFN, as it has property (T).

Answer (score 14):

Browsing through the [archive of solved problems](http://math.nsc.ru/~alglog/kn17arch.pdf) of Kourovka Notebook, I accidentally saw that the same question was asked  by Yu.V. Kuz'min in 1999 (see question 14.52). Apparently the required examples were produced a long time ago by B. Hartley (Hartley, B.,
`On residually finite p-groups.' Symposia Mathematica, Vol. XVII (Convegno sui Gruppi Infiniti, INDAM, Roma, 1973), pp. 225–234. Academic Press, London, 1976. [MR0419611 (54 #7629)](http://ams.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=JOUR&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=&s5=&s6=&s7=Convegno%252520sui%252520Gruppi%252520Infiniti&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=9&mx-pid=419611)).

Hartley showed that for any set of primes $\Pi$ there exists a $3$-generated center-by-metabelian group $G$ which is not residually torsion-free nilpotent and which is residually $p$-finite iff $p \in \Pi$.